# HTML Form Occasionally Won't Type

Tags: html, css, forms, webforms

On some browsers (mostly phone I've noticed), the HTML form will pop up the keyboard, the input fields will glitch and the keyboard disappears; all within a second. This prevents the user from typing.

Here is a video: https://youtube.com/shorts/srxawz9z1IM?feature=share

The form can be found here:
pavepro.com/order

Any and all help is appreciated.

I inspected the code, and think that it might be a viewport problem, but I can't confirm it and I am self taught. Don't know who to ask!

Answer (score 0):

Can you run it with access to the debug console? You might want to try this via Browser Stack, where you can run on mobile, and have access to the debug console to be able to Inspect Elements, and check for Javascript errors. (I'm sure there are other ways to do this too). My hunch would be it's a javascript error, that is causing this odd behaviour. You may wish to initially check the developer tools on desktop - and see if anything odd is being output on the console, or any errors - even if you don't get the odd behaviour on desktop, this may give you a clue.

Further to your comment I took the follow steps:

1. Run under Android studio / Chrome to reproduce the problem (I didn't see any obvious errors either)
2. Took a copy of the page using (save as) and run it on a local server on localhost (putting in my IP address to run it through Android Studio / Chrome)
3. This allowed me to reproduce this locally
4. I then edited the file - removing everything from the header - the problem was gone.
5. I isolated that the issue was due to jQuery calls in the page - removing jQuery the problem goes, adding it back in it comes back.
6. I then put jQuery back and isolated each < script > tag in your body, I found the following causes the issues:

   < script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.pavepro.com/wp-content/themes/Divi/js/scripts.min.js?ver=4.19.5" id="divi-custom-script-js" >< / script >

By removing the DIVI javascript the strange behaviour goes. Now I think you need to look into the custom Javascript that is within the form within Divi, within Wordpress. As the script is minimised it's hard to see what's actually causing the problem. Hopefully now you know what's causing the issue you can debug that jQuery/javascript code further.

Comment: Gave it my best shot, but I did not see any errors.

Comment: Based on this I've taken a deeper look, and have found the root cause is in the Divi javascript Divi/js/scripts.min.js - you will want to debug that further I think

Comment: Thank you! I will take a look into this and talk with the Divi team as well to see if we can sort this out.